# display chips with scrollable for feature in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

i'm using material ui v5 and react 
and try to develop feature which i'm stuck with 
the feature look like that 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQk5E.png)
so i have dynamic array that display as chips .
and i need to use the right and left arrow to scroll
the first row and the second row if there is left in the array .
can be vertical scroll if there easy logic
if there is a library that give me this it will be very helpful.
thank you :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: .......................